# How to get desktop notification in chat application using c# and eStreamchat?

Tags: c#

I am new to C# and .net programming. Actually I am using eStreamchat application for chatting. its working fine. but i need some change in the chatting application like it should give desktop notification if user get any message in chat application but i am not able to change it in eStreamchat application. I have a coding for getting notification in windows form application but how can i integrate it with eStreamchat. eStreamchat is a web application. please any one can help me out... please let me know how i can integrate this code with eStream chat web application above i told for generating notification my code is like this there are three forms like form1.cs, notification.cs and TransDialog .cs. the coding is given below

```
public class TransDialog : System.Windows.Forms.Form   
{
    #region Constructor
    public TransDialog()
    {
        InitializeComponents();
    }
    public TransDialog(bool disposeAtEnd)
    {
        m_bDisposeAtEnd = disposeAtEnd;
        InitializeComponents();
    }
    void InitializeComponents()
    {
        this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
        this.m_clock =  new Timer(this.components);
        this.m_clock.Interval = 100;
        this.SuspendLayout();
        //m_clock
        this.m_clock.Tick += new EventHandler(Animate);
        //TransDialog
        this.Load += new EventHandler(TransDialog_Load);
        this.Closing += new CancelEventHandler(TransDialog_Closing);
        this.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.PerformLayout();
    }
    #endregion

    #region Event handlers
    private void TransDialog_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Opacity = 0.0;
        m_bShowing = true;

        m_clock.Start();
    }

    private void TransDialog_Closing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!m_bForceClose)
        {
            m_origDialogResult = this.DialogResult;
            e.Cancel = true;
            m_bShowing = false;
            m_clock.Start();
        }
        else
        {
            this.DialogResult = m_origDialogResult;
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Private methods
    private void Animate(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (m_bShowing)
        {
            if (this.Opacity < 1)
            {
                this.Opacity += 0.1;
            }
            else
            {
                m_clock.Stop();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (this.Opacity > 0)
            {
                this.Opacity -= 0.1;
            }
            else
            {
                m_clock.Stop();
                m_bForceClose = true;
                this.Close();
                if (m_bDisposeAtEnd)
                    this.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region overrides
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
    #endregion

    #region private variables
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;
    private Timer m_clock;
    private bool m_bShowing = true;
    private bool m_bForceClose = false;
    private DialogResult m_origDialogResult;
    private bool m_bDisposeAtEnd = false;
    #endregion // private variables

    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // TransDialog
        // 
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(284, 262);
        this.Name = "TransDialog";
        this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.TransDialog_Load_1);
        this.ResumeLayout(false);

    }
```

**notification.cs**

```
public class Notification : TransDialog
{
    #region Ctor, init code and dispose
    public Notification()
        : base(true)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void Dispose( bool disposing )
    {
        if( disposing )
        {
            if(components != null)
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
        }
        base.Dispose( disposing );
    }
    #endregion // Ctor and init code

    #region Event handler
    private void Notification_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        int screenWidth = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width;
        int screenHeight = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height;
        this.Left = screenWidth - this.Width;
        this.Top = screenHeight - this.Height;

        timer1.Enabled = true;

        string link = "http://www.geocities.com/basuabhinaba";
        linkLabel1.Links.Add(0, link.Length, link);
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    private void linkLabel1_LinkClicked(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
    {
        string link = e.Link.LinkData.ToString();
        if (link != null && link.Length > 0)
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(link);
    }
    #endregion // Event handler

    #region Windows Form Designer generated code
    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
        System.Resources.ResourceManager resources = new System.Resources.ResourceManager(typeof(Notification));
        this.label1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.pictureBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox();
        this.timer1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer(this.components);
        this.linkLabel1 = new System.Windows.Forms.LinkLabel();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // label1
        // 
        this.label1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(112, 48);
        this.label1.Name = "label1";
        this.label1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(96, 16);
        this.label1.TabIndex = 0;
        this.label1.Text = "You\'ve got email";
        // 
        // pictureBox1
        // 
        this.pictureBox1.Image = ((System.Drawing.Image)(resources.GetObject("pictureBox1.Image")));
        this.pictureBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(8, 8);
        this.pictureBox1.Name = "pictureBox1";
        this.pictureBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(88, 72);
        this.pictureBox1.TabIndex = 1;
        this.pictureBox1.TabStop = false;
        // 
        // timer1
        // 
        this.timer1.Interval = 3000;
        this.timer1.Tick += new System.EventHandler(this.timer1_Tick);
        // 
        // linkLabel1
        // 
        this.linkLabel1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(112, 24);
        this.linkLabel1.Name = "linkLabel1";
        this.linkLabel1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(104, 16);
        this.linkLabel1.TabIndex = 2;
        this.linkLabel1.TabStop = true;
        this.linkLabel1.Text = "Check the web site";
        this.linkLabel1.LinkClicked += new System.Windows.Forms.LinkLabelLinkClickedEventHandler(this.linkLabel1_LinkClicked);
        // 
        // Notification
        // 
        this.AutoScaleBaseSize = new System.Drawing.Size(5, 13);
        this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(234, 88);
        this.Controls.Add(this.linkLabel1);
        this.Controls.Add(this.pictureBox1);
        this.Controls.Add(this.label1);
        this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.FixedToolWindow;
        this.Name = "Notification";
        this.Text = "Notification";
        this.TopMost = true;
        this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Notification_Load);
        this.ResumeLayout(false);

    }
    #endregion

    #region Designer generated variables
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label label1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox pictureBox1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.LinkLabel linkLabel1;
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components;
    #endregion
}
```

**form1.cs**

```
public class Form1 : TransDialog
{
    private System.Windows.Forms.Button button1;
    private System.ComponentModel.Container components = null;

    #region Ctor init and dispose code
    public Form1()
        : base (true)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void Dispose( bool disposing )
    {
        if( disposing )
        {
            if (components != null) 
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
        }
        base.Dispose( disposing );
    }
    #endregion

    #region Windows Form Designer generated code
    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // button1
        // 
        this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(88, 32);
        this.button1.Name = "button1";
        this.button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(112, 24);
        this.button1.TabIndex = 0;
        this.button1.Text = "Show Notification";
        this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
        // 
        // Form1
        // 
        this.AutoScaleBaseSize = new System.Drawing.Size(5, 13);
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(320, 102);
        this.Controls.Add(this.button1);
        this.Name = "Form1";
        this.Text = "Form1";
        this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Load);
        this.ResumeLayout(false);

    }
    #endregion

    #region Event handler
    private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        Notification notifForm = new Notification();
        notifForm.Show();
    }
    #endregion

    [STAThread]
    static void Main() 
    {
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And in web.config add/modify following lines in section  :

```
<services>
      <service name="eStreamChat.ChatEngine">
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="eStreamChat.ChatEngineBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="eStreamChat.IChatEngine" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
```

Comment: Note for admin/moderator. I wasn't able to post in one comment class modification and web.config modification, that's why I made to separated comments. I'll be thankful if you explain me how to make them as one comment. Another problem, which I had I didn't find how to format xml part of comment

Comment: Hi Zaletskiy i am geeting the error after adding services to the web config.

Comment: The contract name 'IMetadataExchange' could not be found in the list of contracts implemented by the service ChatEngine.  Add a ServiceMetadataBehavior to the configuration file or to the ServiceHost directly to enable support for this contract.

Comment: That's sad to hear. I double checked my web.config again and found that I also modified <behaviors><serviceBehaviors> in the following way: <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True"/>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>

Comment: Hi Zaletskiy thanks to you now I have added the services references but tell me how can i get desktop notification if user gets any message. so first thing is how to check whether user got a message and how to notify it through windows form notification.cs.... please help me out

Comment: I'm not expert in eStreamChat, but I propose you to move in the following direction: 1. add at form timer. 2. Add at form ChatEngineClient. 3. At form start try to call methods Start, JoinChatRoom, maybe some other methods  4. Each second call method ( you can use Tick event of timer ) GetEvents of ChatEngineClient. I can't tell you how to call them because it require additional digging in source code, but for now you are in stage where you can debug code of eStreamChat and make conclusions what to pass

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you need some channel of communication between web application and desktop application. AFAIK there is no direct way to send message from web to desktop, so you need some intermediate layer. I propose you one the following scheme:
a:
1. WEB writes to db some marker + message
2. Desktop each second checks is there some marker, and if finds it reads message.
b          (it's actually variation of a): 
1. Web writes to xml some marker + message
2. Desktop reads xml in a search of marker and if finds reads message.
c:
1. Create TCP Listener in C# it is TcpListener
2. Add TcpClient 
3. Organize communication between them. One of useful examples is here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20972/Notification-Client-and-Server-Written-in-C
d: quite reliable way is to RabbitMQ http://www.rabbitmq.com which has quite good perfomance

Comment: Hi Zaletskiy as you understood my problem is to show desktop notification if user gets any message in chat application. you told that i need to write some tcp client Listener. can you explain me how i can write it. please explain me in more elaboration manner.

Comment: TcpListener is one of the options, and note, not the easiest one. TcpListener is implemented already by Microsoft. Documentation is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener%28v=vs.110%29.aspx . You just need to use it. One of the ways how to use it is mentioned here:

Answer (score 0):

Let me try. I suppose you speak about http://www.estreamchat.com. There it mentioned that source code of it can be downloaded https://github.com/eStream/eStreamChat . After downloading the source code I found the following: project eStreamChat. Inside of project eStreamChat there is a file ChatEngine.svc. It means that you can reference it as service. You can do it with right clicking at your project at part References, and choosing Add Service Refrerence [image]

there you can choose either your current project, or if you deployed already estreamchat somewhere, then you can pick it from that area. Inside of ChangEngine.svc.cs there are methods JoinChatRoom, LeaveChatRoom, GetEvents, SendMessage, SendCommand, BroadcastVideo, StopVideoBroadcast, etc.

After you reference Service you'll be able to add join win forms with estreamchat

Comment: Hi @Zaletskiy thanks for your reply. Actually as you told like i need to add the services reference to my windows form project but when i am adding it its giving error like **The HTML document does not contain Web service discovery information.
Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'http://localhost:63416/ChatEngine.svc'.
There was no endpoint listening at http://localhost:63416/ChatEngine.svc that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException,

Comment: i googled this then got that i need to add some thing in web config of my web app that is already there

Comment: actually i need to add service model behavior etc its already there so i am not able to understand what is problem please help me out....

Answer (score 0):

Please try following changes:
1. Extract into interface IChatEngine class ChatEngine. ChatEngine.svc.cs should look like this:

```
/* This file is part of eStreamChat.
 * 
 * eStreamChat is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
 * it under the terms of the GNU Affero General Public License as published by
 * the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
 * (at your option) any later version. 
 * 
 * eStreamChat is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
 * but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
 * MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
 * GNU Affero General Public License for more details.
 * 
 * You should have received a copy of the GNU Affero General Public License
 * along with eStreamChat. If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
 */
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Activation;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Web;
using eStreamChat.Classes;
using eStreamChat.Interfaces;
using System.Net;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.Practices.Unity;

namespace eStreamChat
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IChatEngine
    {
        [OperationContract]
        ChatEngine.JoinChatRoomResult JoinChatRoom(string chatRoomId, string href);

        [OperationContract]
        void LeaveChatRoom(string chatRoomId, string token, string messengerTargetUserId);

        [OperationContract]
        ChatEngine.EventsResult GetEvents(string chatRoomId, string token, long fromTimestamp, string messengerTargetUserId);

        [OperationContract]
        ChatEngine.SendMessageResult SendMessage(string chatRoomId, string token, string toUserId, string message, 
                                                      bool bold = false, bool italic = false, bool underline = false, string fontName = null, int? fontSize = null,
                                                      string color = null);

        [OperationContract]
        ChatEngine.SendMessageResult SendCommand(string chatRoomId, string token, string targetUserId, string command);

        [OperationContract]
        string BroadcastVideo(string prevGuid, string token, int chatRoomId, string targetUserId);

        [OperationContract]
        void StopVideoBroadcast(string token, int chatRoomId);

        void StopVideoBroadcast(string userId, string chatRoomId);
    }


    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
    public class ChatEngine : IChatEngine
    {
        private static IChatRoomProvider chatRoomProvider;
        private static IChatRoomStorage chatRoomStorage;
        private static IChatUserProvider chatUserProvider;
        private static IChatSettings chatSettingsProvider;
        private static IMessengerPresenceProvider messengerProvider;

        private static bool importsSatisfied = false;

        public ChatEngine()
        {
            if (!importsSatisfied)
            {
                lock (Global.CompositionLock)
                {
                    chatRoomProvider = Global.Container.Resolve<IChatRoomProvider>();
                    chatRoomStorage = Global.Container.Resolve<IChatRoomStorage>();
                    chatUserProvider = Global.Container.Resolve<IChatUserProvider>();
                    chatSettingsProvider = Global.Container.Resolve<IChatSettings>();
                    if (Global.Container.IsRegistered<IMessengerPresenceProvider>())
                        messengerProvider = Global.Container.Resolve<IMessengerPresenceProvider>();
                }
                importsSatisfied = true;
            }

            CleanTimedOutUsers.Initialize(chatUserProvider, chatRoomStorage);
        }


        public JoinChatRoomResult JoinChatRoom(string chatRoomId, string href)
        {
            if (href != null) HttpContext.Current.Items["href"] = href;

            var result = new JoinChatRoomResult
                             {
                                 FileTransferEnabled = chatSettingsProvider.EnableFileTransfer,
                                 VideoChatEnabled = chatSettingsProvider.EnableVideoChat,
                                 FlashMediaServer = chatSettingsProvider.FlashMediaServer
                             };

            User user;
            try
            {
                user = chatUserProvider.GetCurrentlyLoggedUser();
            }
            catch (System.Security.SecurityException err)
            {
                result.Error = err.Message;
                return result;
            }

            if (user == null)
            {
                string loginUrl = chatUserProvider.GetLoginUrl(href);
                result.Error = "You need to login in order to use the chat!";
                if (loginUrl != null)
                {
                    result.Error += " Redirecting to login page...";
                    result.RedirectUrl = loginUrl;
                }
                return result;
            }

            Room room = chatRoomProvider.GetChatRoom(chatRoomId);

            if (room == null)
            {
                result.Error = "The specified chat room does not exist!";
                return result;
            }

            #region Messenger
            var url = (new Uri(href));
            var queryKeyValues = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(url.Query);
            var isInitiator = queryKeyValues["init"];
            var targetUserId = queryKeyValues["target"];
            bool alreadyConnected = href.IndexOf('#') == -1 ? false : (href.Substring(href.IndexOf('#')) == "#connected");
            #endregion

            string reason;

            //if messenger
            if (room.Id == "-2")
            {
                //check chat access only for the initiators
                if (isInitiator == "1" && !chatRoomProvider.HasChatAccess(user.Id, room.Id, out reason))
                {
                    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(reason))
                        result.Error = "You don't have access to the messenger.";
                    else
                        result.Error = reason;

                    return result;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (!chatRoomProvider.HasChatAccess(user.Id, room.Id, out reason))
                {
                    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(reason))
                        result.Error = String.Format("You don't have access to chat room '{0}'.", room.Name);
                    else
                        result.Error = reason;

                    return result;
                }
            }

            // Ignore max users limit for messengerRoom (roomId = -2)
            if (room.Id != "-2" && chatRoomStorage.GetUsersInRoom(room.Id).Length >= room.MaxUsers)
            {
                result.Error = String.Format("The chat room '{0}' is full. Please try again later.", room.Name);

                return result;
            }

            chatRoomStorage.AddUserToRoom(room.Id, user.Id);
            chatRoomStorage.AddMessage(room.Id, new Message
                                                    {
                                                        Content =
                                                            string.Format("User {0} has joined the chat.",
                                                                          user.DisplayName),
                                                        FromUserId = user.Id,
                                                        ToUserId = String.IsNullOrEmpty(targetUserId) ? null : targetUserId,
                                                        MessageType = MessageTypeEnum.UserJoined,
                                                        Timestamp = Miscellaneous.GetTimestamp()
                                                    });

            #region Messenger

            //delete all messages when starting messenger (not reloading it)
            if (isInitiator != null && !alreadyConnected)
            {
                chatRoomStorage.DeleteAllMessagesFor(room.Id, user.Id);
            }

            if (!alreadyConnected && isInitiator == "1" && !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(targetUserId))
            {
                try
                {
                    var targetUser = chatUserProvider.GetUser(targetUserId);

                    //Not sure that MessengerUrl should be constructed here?! timestamp and hash are tied to
                    //the implementation
                    var timestamp = DateTime.Now.ToFileTimeUtc();
                    var hash = Miscellaneous.CalculateChatAuthHash(targetUserId, user.Id, timestamp.ToString());

                    var request = new ChatRequest
                                      {
                                          FromThumbnailUrl = user.ThumbnailUrl,
                                          FromProfileUrl = user.ProfileUrl,
                                          FromUserId = user.Id,
                                          FromUsername = user.DisplayName,
                                          ToUserId = targetUserId,
                                          ToUsername = targetUser.DisplayName,
                                          MessengerUrl =
                                              String.Format("{0}?init=0&id={1}&target={2}&timestamp={3}&hash={4}",
                                                            url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path), targetUserId, user.Id,
                                                            timestamp, hash)
                                      };

                    messengerProvider.AddChatRequest(request);
                }
                catch (System.Security.SecurityException) { }
            }
            #endregion

            result.ChatRoomName = room.Name;
            result.ChatRoomTopic = room.Topic;
            result.Users = chatRoomStorage.GetUsersInRoom(room.Id).Select(chatUserProvider.GetUser).ToArray();
            result.Token = chatRoomStorage.GenerateUserToken(user.Id);
            result.UserId = user.Id;
            result.IsAdmin = chatUserProvider.IsChatAdmin(user.Id, room.Id);

            StopVideoBroadcast(user.Id, room.Id);
            result.Broadcasts = chatRoomStorage.GetBroadcasts(room.Id, user.Id);

            return result;
        }


        public void LeaveChatRoom(string chatRoomId, string token, string messengerTargetUserId)
        {
            string userId = chatRoomStorage.GetUserIdByToken(token);
            if (userId == null) return;
            var user = chatUserProvider.GetUser(userId);

            Room room = chatRoomProvider.GetChatRoom(chatRoomId);
            if (room == null) return;

            //do not leave the room if messenger. The user will eventually time out when all the 
            // messenger windows are closed.
            if (chatRoomId != "-2")
                chatRoomStorage.RemoveUserFromRoom(room.Id, user.Id);

            chatRoomStorage.AddMessage(room.Id, new Message
                                                    {
                                                        Content =
                                                            string.Format("User {0} has left the chat.",
                                                                          user.DisplayName),
                                                        FromUserId = user.Id,
                                                        ToUserId = messengerTargetUserId,
                                                        MessageType = MessageTypeEnum.UserLeft,
                                                        Timestamp = Miscellaneous.GetTimestamp()
                                                    });

            StopVideoBroadcast(userId, room.Id);
        }


        public EventsResult GetEvents(string chatRoomId, string token, long fromTimestamp, string messengerTargetUserId)
        {
            var result = new EventsResult();
            string userId = chatRoomStorage.GetUserIdByToken(token);
            if (userId == null)
            {
                result.Error = "Chat disconnected!";
                return result;
            }

            chatRoomStorage.UpdateOnline(chatRoomId, userId);

            //get all the messages for the current user
            IEnumerable<Message> messages = chatRoomStorage.GetMessages(chatRoomId, userId, fromTimestamp);

            //if in messenger mode then filter messages to be only from the target user or from the current user himself
            if (messengerTargetUserId != null)
            {
                messages = messages.Where(m => m.FromUserId == userId || m.FromUserId == messengerTargetUserId);
            }

            //get only joined, left and kicked messages for ignored users
            result.Messages = messages.Where(m =>!chatUserProvider.IsUserIgnored(userId, m.FromUserId) ||
                                                m.MessageType == MessageTypeEnum.UserJoined ||
                                                m.MessageType == MessageTypeEnum.UserLeft ||
                                                m.MessageType == MessageTypeEnum.Kicked).ToArray();

            var joinMessages = messages.Where(m => m.MessageType == MessageTypeEnum.UserJoined);
            var leaveMessages = messages.Where(m => m.MessageType == MessageTypeEnum.UserLeft || m.MessageType == MessageTypeEnum.Kicked);

            var joinedUsers = joinMessages.Where(j => !leaveMessages.Any(l => l.FromUserId == j.FromUserId && l.Timestamp > j.Timestamp)).Select(
                                m => chatUserProvider.GetUser(m.FromUserId)).ToArray();
            var leftUsers = leaveMessages.Where(l => !joinMessages.Any(j => j.FromUserId == l.FromUserId && j.Timestamp > l.Timestamp)).Select(
                                m => chatUserProvider.GetUser(m.FromUserId)).ToArray();

            result.UsersJoined = joinedUsers;
            result.UsersLeft = leftUsers;

            if (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PollingInterval"] != null)
                result.CallInterval = Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PollingInterval"]);

            return result;
        }


        public SendMessageResult SendMessage(string chatRoomId, string token, string toUserId, string message, 
            bool bold = false, bool italic = false, bool underline = false, string fontName = null, int? fontSize = null,
            string color = null)
        {
            var result = new SendMessageResult();
            string userId = chatRoomStorage.GetUserIdByToken(token);
            if (userId == null)
            {
                result.Error = "Chat disconnected!";
                return result;
            }

            if (!chatRoomStorage.IsUserInRoom(chatRoomId, userId))
            {
                result.Error = "Chat disconnected!";
                return result;
            }

            // TODO: Process message (trim, filter)
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(color))
                color = Regex.Replace(color, @"[^\w\#]", String.Empty); // Strip dangerous input
            var formatOptions = new MessageFormatOptions
                                           {
                                               Bold = bold,
                                               Italic = italic,
                                               Underline = underline,
                                               Color = color,
                                               FontName = fontName,
                                           };
            if (fontSize.HasValue) formatOptions.FontSize = fontSize.Value;
            chatRoomStorage.AddMessage(chatRoomId, new Message
                                                       {
                                                           Content = WebUtility.HtmlEncode(message),
                                                           FromUserId = userId,
                                                           ToUserId = toUserId,
                                                           MessageType = MessageTypeEnum.User,
                                                           Timestamp = Miscellaneous.GetTimestamp(),
                                                           FormatOptions = formatOptions
                                                       });

            return result;
        }


        public SendMessageResult SendCommand(string chatRoomId, string token, string targetUserId, string command)
        {
            var result = new SendMessageResult();
            string userId = chatRoomStorage.GetUserIdByToken(token);
            if (userId == null)
            {
                result.Error = "Chat disconnected!";
                return result;
            }

            if (!chatRoomStorage.IsUserInRoom(chatRoomId, userId))
            {
                result.Error = "Chat disconnected!";
                return result;
            }

            var user = chatUserProvider.GetUser(userId);
            var targetUser = chatUserProvider.GetUser(targetUserId);

            if (command == "ignore")
            {
                chatUserProvider.IgnoreUser(userId, targetUserId);
            }
            else if (command == "kick")
            {
                if (chatUserProvider.IsChatAdmin(userId, chatRoomId) && chatRoomStorage.IsUserInRoom(chatRoomId, targetUserId))
                {
                    chatRoomStorage.RemoveUserFromRoom(chatRoomId, targetUserId);

                    chatRoomStorage.AddMessage(chatRoomId, new Message
                    {
                        Content =
                            string.Format("User {0} has been kicked off the room by {1}.",
                                          targetUser.DisplayName, user.DisplayName),
                        FromUserId = targetUserId,
                        MessageType = MessageTypeEnum.Kicked,
                        Timestamp = Miscellaneous.GetTimestamp()
                    });
                }
            }
            else if (command == "ban")
            {
                if (chatUserProvider.IsChatAdmin(userId, chatRoomId) && chatRoomStorage.IsUserInRoom(chatRoomId, targetUserId))
                {
                    chatRoomStorage.RemoveUserFromRoom(chatRoomId, targetUserId);

                    chatRoomStorage.AddMessage(chatRoomId, new Message
                    {
                        Content =
                            string.Format("User {0} has been kicked off the room by {1} (Banned).",
                                          targetUser.DisplayName, user.DisplayName),
                        FromUserId = targetUserId,
                        MessageType = MessageTypeEnum.Kicked,
                        Timestamp = Miscellaneous.GetTimestamp()
                    });

                    chatRoomProvider.BanUser(chatRoomId, userId, targetUserId);
                }
            }
            else if (command == "slap")
            {
                chatRoomStorage.AddMessage(chatRoomId, new Message
                {
                    Content =
                        string.Format("{0} slaps {1} around with a large trout.",
                                      user.DisplayName, targetUser.DisplayName),
                    FromUserId = userId,
                    MessageType = MessageTypeEnum.System,
                    Timestamp = Miscellaneous.GetTimestamp()
                });
            }

            return result;
        }


        public string BroadcastVideo(string prevGuid, string token, int chatRoomId, string targetUserId)
        {
            if (!chatSettingsProvider.EnableVideoChat) return null;

            string userId = chatRoomStorage.GetUserIdByToken(token);
            string guid = prevGuid ?? Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

            chatRoomStorage.AddMessage(chatRoomId.ToString(), new Message
            {
                Content = guid,
                FromUserId = userId,
                ToUserId = targetUserId,
                MessageType = MessageTypeEnum.VideoBroadcast,
                Timestamp = Miscellaneous.GetTimestamp()
            });

            chatRoomStorage.RegisterBroadcast(chatRoomId.ToString(), userId, targetUserId, guid);
            return guid;
        }


        public void StopVideoBroadcast(string token, int chatRoomId)
        {
            string userId = chatRoomStorage.GetUserIdByToken(token);

            StopVideoBroadcast(userId, chatRoomId.ToString());
        }

        public void StopVideoBroadcast(string userId, string chatRoomId)
        {
            if (chatRoomStorage.UnregisterUserBroadcasts(chatRoomId, userId))
            {
                chatRoomStorage.AddMessage(chatRoomId, new Message
                {
                    FromUserId = userId,
                    MessageType = MessageTypeEnum.StopVideoBroadcast,
                    Timestamp = Miscellaneous.GetTimestamp()
                });
            }
        }

        #region Nested type: EventsResult

        public class EventsResult
        {
            public string Error;
            public Message[] Messages;
            public User[] UsersJoined;
            public User[] UsersLeft;
            public int? CallInterval;
        }

        #endregion

        #region Nested type: JoinChatRoomResult


        public class JoinChatRoomResult
        {
            public string ChatRoomName;
            public string ChatRoomTopic;
            public string Error;
            public string RedirectUrl;
            public string Token;
            public string UserId;
            public User[] Users;
            public bool IsAdmin;
            public bool FileTransferEnabled;
            public bool VideoChatEnabled;
            public string FlashMediaServer;
            public Dictionary<string, string> Broadcasts;
        }

        #endregion

        #region Nested type: SendMessageResult

        public class SendMessageResult
        {
            public string Error;
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Zaletskiy thank u for your response Actually i have done as you said to change in webconfig and chatengine.svc  but then also it not adding the services refrence. its telling that The contract name 'eStreamChat.IChatEngine' could not be found in the list of contracts implemented by the service 'ChatEngine please help me out....

Comment: Have you created inerface IChatEngine and modified class ChatEngine?